# How to get data from array in object in php?

Tags: php, html, laravel

In a database table - `about_us`, I have a column named `subject`

I am trying to make a table from this data in laravel

Column `subject` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name1": "1",
        "name2": "2"
    },
    {
        "name1": "3",
        "name2": "4"
    }
]
```

from controller

```
public function about()
{
    $about  = About::find(1);
    return view('pages.about-us', compact('about'));
}
```

in `about-us.blade.php`

```
{{$about->subject}}
```

How can I extract the data to make a table like this?
[image]

Comment: You could start writing some code for that - what have you tried, where are you stuck? Without any details about the logic, there is no way to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of your `subject` property is a JSON string. Which means that you will have to decode it through `json_decode()` into an array/object before your can iterate over it.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>right</th>
            <th>left</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(json_decode($about->subject) as $subject)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $subject->name1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subject->name2 }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try code below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>right</td>
        <td>left</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach(json_decode($about->subject) as $subject)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $subject->name1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $subject->name2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th><strong>right</strong></th>
    <th><strong>left</strong></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($about->subject as $subject)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $subject->name1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $subject->name2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Just loop over the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table>
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Right</th>

        <th>Left</th>

       </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($about->subject as $subject)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $subject->name1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $subject->name2 }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach


</tbody>
</table>
```